# Github encrypts data of push and pulls?

Tags: git, cryptography, github

When i do push and pulls my data are encrypts?

I know when I establish the connection with github is used the SSH keys and RSA algorithms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Your pushes/pulls are going through SSH.